# How to Convert string in xml and loop the Node?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a simple xml string. I am trying to convert it into xml and need to save 2 records in DB for it.
First node will go seperate record and 2nd node will go as a seperate record. But it's not working.  This is string.

```
$getXml = '<Nodes>
<NODE>
<RANGE-START>200</RANGE-START>
<RANGE-END>244</RANGE-END>
<QTY>45</QTY>
</NODE>
<NODE>
<RANGE-START>50</RANGE-START>
<RANGE-END>52</RANGE-END>
<QTY>2</QTY>
</NODE>
</NODES>
';
```

This is code

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($getXml);
foreach( $xml->node as $item ) 
{
    echo $arrXml = $item->{'RANGE-START'};
}
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid, there should be only 1 root node (you have 2 `<node>` elements).  Add a node round all of the XML and it should work.

Comment: where's the parent node? it's invalid that's why it doesn't work. just wrap it around with a `<parent>markup here</parent>` or something to make it valid

Comment: While developing, make sure you [show all errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings). This should throw a bunch of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one main tag in the XML that will contain all the nodes.

Try this:

```
$getXml = '<nodes>
<node>
<RANGE-START>200</RANGE-START>
<RANGE-END>244</RANGE-END>
<QTY>45</QTY>
</node>
<node>
<RANGE-START>50</RANGE-START>
<RANGE-END>52</RANGE-END>
<QTY>2</QTY>
</node>
</nodes>';

$xml=simplexml_load_string($getXml);
foreach( $xml->node as $item )
{
    echo $arrXml[] = $item->{'RANGE-START'};
}
var_dump($arrXml);
```

If you want to save the whole node, then you need to save it to xml:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($getXml);
foreach( $xml->node as $item )
{
    echo $arrXml[] = $item->saveXML();
}
var_dump($arrXml);
```

Comment: i have changed format of xml. But i need to save $getxml 2 times in DB like first record xml will be <nodes>
<nodes><node>
<RANGE-START>200</RANGE-START>
<RANGE-END>244</RANGE-END>
<QTY>45</QTY>
</node> </nodes> and rnd record xml will be <node>
<RANGE-START>50</RANGE-START>
<RANGE-END>52</RANGE-END>
<QTY>2</QTY>
</node>
</nodes>

Comment: @parv then just save the node to xml again `echo $arrXml[] = $item->saveXML();`

Answer (score 0):

XML is case sensitive. You will have to address the `NODE` elements as `$xml->NODE`.

```
$getXml = '<NODES>
<NODE>
<RANGE-START>200</RANGE-START>
<RANGE-END>244</RANGE-END>
<QTY>45</QTY>
</NODE>
<NODE>
<RANGE-START>50</RANGE-START>
<RANGE-END>52</RANGE-END>
<QTY>2</QTY>
</NODE>
</NODES>
';

$xml=simplexml_load_string($getXml);
foreach( $xml->NODE as $item ) 
{
    var_dump((string)$item->{'RANGE-START'});
}
```

Output:

```
string(3) "200"
string(2) "50"
```